# Spring Security [Spring Boot App] : How to block a user?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

My project is on Employee Exit Process and once the employee is relieved, it is expected to block the employee from logging in **and not** delete the employee.

Attempts:

1. `userObject.isCredentialsNonExpired() = false`
2. `userObject.isAccountNonLocked() = false`
3. `userObject.isAccountNonExpired() = false`
4. `userObject.isEnabled() = false`

Even when I modify all these four values, login still works for the user.

```java
@Autowired 
EmployeeRepository empRep; 

@Override 
public EmployeeEntity loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException { 
    EmployeeEntity emp = empRep.findByUserId(username); 
    if (emp == null) { 
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User trapped in singularity"); 
    } 
    return emp; 
}
```

Comment: All options are working. The problem has to be in your code. Show your `UserDetailService`.

Comment: `EmployeeEntity` is a table which has many fields and `implements Serializable, UserDetails`.

Comment: Also, in `@RestController` when i try to modify value as `employee.isEnabled() = false` where `employee` is object of `EmployeeEntity` it shows error.